# Unable to use curl to get a token with Django OAuth Toolkit

Tags: django, bash, curl, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am learn Django and Django REST framework. I want use oAuth as autorization system.
I installed Django OAuth Toolkit and registred new App.Then, I tried to get token for my app, but I couldn't get it:

```
19:04 ~$ curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=123" http://tygkDGuF.re@HmpJB!G=oi5pHtbgxW96I9w8iTd0:zFpyRXwgUKglYAs6b=v8UwlA3qqxZr!=hn3PgzQQ5CgO=OVR-O26reO;T8xcn;xcurcbC7kPr8r-York9TIEKKEM6EFRUOhR:oU!=S3A;QQ1pmAK8dNso48KfYNgYO_F@http://127.0.0.1:8080/o/token/
bash: !G=oi5pHtbgxW96I9w8iTd0: event not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes around your last parameter:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=123" 'http://tygkDGuF.re@HmpJB!G=oi5pHtbgxW96I9w8iTd0:zFpyRXwgUKglYAs6b=v8UwlA3qqxZr!=hn3PgzQQ5CgO=OVR-O26reO;T8xcn;xcurcbC7kPr8r-York9TIEKKEM6EFRUOhR:oU!=S3A;QQ1pmAK8dNso48KfYNgYO_F@http://127.0.0.1:8080/o/token/'
```

If you don't then the shell will interpret `!` as an operator for recalling history. And `;` will be interpreted as command separators.

Answer (score 3):

I used http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/:

```
response = requests.post(
    'http://localhost:8000/o/token/',
    data={
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'you',
        'password': 'secret',
        'client_id': 'WpDs.u9yrWD3js;fYq?cog;MvTiq0Bj02r8LTL_v',
        'client_secret': 'c1W2:PzVsccsIt_G_uxnwE_TC08z14IKqYYKy0DJAok;_B?RvuVashIsARqhGwF=ChoBJveA7LvB;C?IeXyp?0ZiyBtg9;tSwTjVdC.K_f@n=K;@V;2:VoX@IhPyiHzC'
    }
)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried this:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=name&password=123" 'http://wHMBrLRjQU_!;pYIPgLGurD2SIYH.9r19!h7JSds:wCQ?KHaoVb;aS:-sqCVkkNwrwGP3B?hD9yZTGY;zFCvbR5H8Fy=mh79KYFQBtIJWza380yFF!OHeb-HyFyGtSY54oUK;_qPF4nsaAI0mt_INr.JQ0vdUgAluWPI9EeDk@127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'wHMBrLRjQU_!;pYIPgLGurD2SIYH.9r19!h7JSds'
```

I did everything on a manual ([link](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.0/rest-framework/getting_started.html))

Answer (score 1):

In my case, below is work:

```
curl -X POST -d 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=password&username=YOUR_USERNAME&password=YOUR_PASSWORD' http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

Note i used signs '***'.

Answer (score 0):

And a Javascript solution to get token from django-oauth-toolkit:

```
async function getToken () {
    let res = await fetch("https://<your_domain>/o/token/", {
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            grant_type: 'password',
            username: '<user_name>',
            password: '<user_pass>',
            client_id: '<client_app_id>',
            client_secret: '<client_pass>'
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        method: "POST"
    })
    return res.json();
}
console.log(await getToken());
```

Your client application **authorisation grant type** should be: "Resource owner password-based"
[image: oauth client application: Auth grant type]

P.S. I've failed to get token via **"Content-Type": "application/json"**, not sure why (django-oauth-toolkit documentation says nothing about that).